# #!/usr/bin/env ruby ignored from within a Git hook

Tags: ruby, git, githooks

I'm trying to write a Git hook (`commit-msg`) in Ruby, but it seems my script is not run under Ruby, but under SH.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
```

Throws me a node.js error because of node's require command under SH.

Or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'hello'
```

Tells me there's no command `puts`.

I'm running OSX 10.8.5, using RVM with ZSH. Everything seems to be configured alright since if I run the script from my terminal without the git hook it runs alright.

What is the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved this myself, there was an empty line before `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.